# Removing saved credenials from "C:\Windows\explorer.exe"

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2

How can we remove the saved credentials from "C:\Windows\explorer.exe" process?

Answer (score 1):

`rundll32.exe keymgr.dll,KRShowKeyMgr` Opens the credentials manager. You can remove or edit any stored credential in there.

Answer (score 1):

Open `Control Panel -> User Account -> Credentials` 
From here you can delete the saved credential, under the `Windows credentials` category.